# How to control build mode(debug or release) in cmake?

Tags: cmake

Anyone knows?

Seems by default all libraries/executables are built in debug mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can be controlled by setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable, see [cmake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable:CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE).

Answer (score 1):

an alternative solution is: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")` or `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g")` if you are using C++ or C.